# Using Putty to use local machine as proxy to Internet from remote machine?

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty

(N00b here)

I have a remote server (Ubuntu) that is behind a firewall. Because of said firewall, it cannot download package updates from the internet.

My local machine (Windows) can connect to the internet. 
I can connect to the server from my local machine via Putty.

Is there a way to set up Putty so that the remote host can use my local machine as a proxy to reach the internet?

Comment: Sure it is, but it sounds like you really should be solving a different problem.

Comment: Do you have a Linux (non-Cygwin/non-WSL) client with OpenSSH in it, and do you have root access to the server?

Comment: Yes I have root/sudo access on the server.
No I do not have another Linux machine available (short of spinning up a local VM and adding another level of complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though that would be much more difficult than simply allowing the ubuntu server to bring its package updates in through the firewall.

Try seeing what firewall rule is denying the updates, then allow for the ubuntu server to get its updates. Be sure to only allow that exact server the exact privileges it needs to get its updates.

Comment: I do not have access to the Firewall rules.

My boss basically told me "Find a work-around". Short-term, one-off, update the one package that's breaking...then get the firewall team to deal with the long-term solution later.

Comment: If you cant even see the firewall rules, you're really working in the dark, whether you attempt to change how the server gets its updates to work around the rules. 

If no sort of inspection is in place on the firewall to designed to block this sort of thing, your proposed solution sounds possible. 

I do not have the exact experience on how to set it up. Hopefully someone else can weigh in.

Comment: Like Gregg says, configure a proxy server on your windows machine (i have no idea how to do this) - Ubuntu can be configured to use the proxy pretty simply in the network control panel

Comment: First, tis "answer" is not an answer; it's a guess at most. To Alan Knightly: If you don't have root access, you cannot install software, and if you have root access you can access the firewall rules. If you and your boss have no idea both, get a basic book or training! Otherwise leave Linux alone. There's nothing worse than a badly maintained installation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SWM that the proper solution is to get Ubuntu server unblocked since that'll future-proof it. If your boss said find a workaround be sure to voice your thoughts that clearly it will be a subpar (think ducktape) solution & doing so is clearly breaking the networking-admin rules they have setup (the firewall).

Workaround ideas:

1. Check if Windows PC has proxy settings, if so mimic those to the Ubuntu server
2. Download the packages on your PC & copy them to ubuntu server for offline installation